# Is it possible to load Wordpress (Elementor) header & footer templates into external app?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm looking for information on how to pull in the header/footer separately from a WP install that's using Elementor.

I have an Angular application that I'm trying to make the header/footer match the WP site. It seems like this should be easy but Elementor templates seem to just include the header and footer whether you want them or not. I was hoping there was a way to have 2 pages that could load the header and footer respectively.

Is this possible? If so, how do I go about doing it?

Basically, I want a URL I can hit that just gives me the Elementor header HTML and a URL that does the same for the footer HTML.

Any guidance would be appreciated here. :)